# Limit of 0/0 type

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital, probability-limit-theorems

I would like to calculate the limit
\begin{equation}
\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{h}{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi h}} \int_{-d}^{d}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2h})dx}
\end{equation}
It is of the 0/0 type. First, I change the limit into the following form
\begin{equation}
\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{h}{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-d/\sqrt{h}}^{d/\sqrt{h}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})dx}
\end{equation}

Then, I use the L'Hospital's Rule once, it becomes
\begin{equation}
\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{h^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp(-\frac{d^2}{2h})}
\end{equation}

I can keep using the L'Hospital's Rule. But it is always the 0/0 type without end.

Comment: For the limit to be of the form $\;0/0\;$ it must be that the second summand in the denominator tends to $\;1\;$ when $\;h\to0\;$. I can't see clearly why this is so...

Comment: Try letting $h=1/t$.

Comment: @DonAntonio It's $-x^2/2$ not $-x^2$. It perfectly tends to one.

Comment: @DonAntonio: when h->0, it is the integration of normal distribution from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. So it is 1.

Comment: You can do $\sqrt{h}$ only for $h>0$.

Comment: @egreg It won't hurt to assume that $h>0$.

Comment: @user125056 I don't see why.

Comment: @egreg $h>0$ is default. See $h$ is inside the square root in the original expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your final expression is $$\sqrt{2\pi} \lim_{h \to 0} \exp\left(\frac{d^2}{2h}\right) h^{3/2}$$

Take the logarithm of the thing in the limit: it's $\dfrac{d^2}{2h} + \frac{3}{2} \log(h) = \frac{1}{h} \left(\dfrac{d^2}{2} + \frac{3}{2} h \log(h)\right)$.

Since $x \log(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$, the bracket clearly tends to $\dfrac{d^2}{2}$, so the logarithm of your original limit is $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{d^2}{2h}$, which is $\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative approach: using [the well-known asymptotic approximation](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Erfc/10/01/) $\text{Erfc}(z)\sim \frac{e^{-z^2}}{z\sqrt{\pi}}$ we get

$$ \lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{h}{\text{Erfc}\left(\frac{d}{\sqrt{2h}}\right)}=\lim_{h\to 0^+}hd\sqrt{2\pi h} e^{\frac{d^2}{2h}} = +\infty.$$